# Tk - segfaults when I use widget (button, text)

Tags: dependencies, tk-toolkit, fontconfig

I have compiled Tcl/Tk into my application. When I open my application, I get a window (due to Tk_init) which I can manipulate:

```
> wm title . "mysh"
> wm geometry . 300x300
```

But when I try button or any of the other widgets it segfaults

```
> button .b
Segmentation fault
```

I loaded this in gdb and ran a back trace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  [Switching to Thread 182897358752 (LWP 14112)]
0x0000000100000000 in ?? ()
  (gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000fe3004 in XML_ParseBuffer ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#2  0x0000000000fa4955 in FcConfigParseAndLoad ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#3  0x0000000000f9d3cc in FcInitLoadConfig ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#4  0x0000000000f9d416 in FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#5  0x0000000000f9d5bd in FcInit ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#6  0x0000000000f97015 in FcConfigGetCurrent ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#7  0x0000000000f98906 in FcConfigSubstituteWithPat ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#8  0x0000000000edf28c in InitFont ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#9  0x0000000000edf52f in TkpGetFontFromAttributes ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#10 0x0000000000f00c4c in Tk_AllocFontFromObj ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#11 0x0000000000efa4d2 in DoObjConfig ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#12 0x0000000000efaa3a in Tk_InitOptions ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#13 0x0000000000e70db2 in ButtonCreate ()
  at <local>/software/gcc_64/include/c++/3.3.6/bits/stl_pair.h:83
#14 0x0000000001588581 in TclEvalObjvInternal ()
```

I think there is some problem with Fonts. Any idea to fix this?

EDIT 1 (Apr 01 2011):

```
% uname -a
Linux scdbuild04 2.6.9-67.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Nov 16 12:49:06 EST 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% ldd libtk8.5.so 
libX11.so.6 => /usr/X11R6/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x0000002a957b7000)
libXss.so.1 => /usr/X11R6/lib64/libXss.so.1 (0x0000002a959b0000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/X11R6/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x0000002a95ab3000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000002a95bc5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/tls/libm.so.6 (0x0000002a95cc8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/tls/libc.so.6 (0x0000002a95e4e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000552aaaa000)
```

EDIT 2 (04 Apr 2011)

```
% cat /etc/*-release 
CentOS release 4.6 (Final)

% cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.9-67.ELsmp (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)) #1 SMP Fri Nov 16 12:49:06 EST 2007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked this question on [comp.lang.tcl](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/browse_frm/thread/a4fd47928ce8612e), and the *workaround* is to specify `--disable-xft` when configuring Tk.

I suspect that the real cause is a failure to link an XML parser, which was reported as being a potential issue on some recent versions of Linux due to a system change to the way that transitive dependencies are processed. (I forget which vendor is responsible; I wasn't paying that much attention to the developer discussion where this was thrashed out recently.) Can you report what `ldd` reports for the Tk library (without the workaround) and what exact OS you're building on? Also, exactly which version of Tk are you trying to build against? Also note that it is enormously more helpful to use the `--enable-symbols` configure option to Tcl and Tk when tracing down a problem, as that lets you get better information in stack traces.

Comment: Added `ldd` and `uname -a` info to the post. I will post the stack trace with `--enable-symbols` turned on later.

Comment: I compiled with `--enable-symbols` and the `bt` in `gdb` gave the same information. Should enable any other switch in `gdb` or `tcl/tk` compilation?

Comment: @Anand: I was actually wondering which vendor. Red Hat? Suse? Debian?

Comment: @Anand: This is indeed the issue relating to transient linking, which RH turned off fairly recently. (Thanks a bunch for *nothing*, RH!) IIRC, it's missing the Xft and expat libraries (which fontconfig depends on, but Tk doesn't _directly_) but I might be wrong. I think there's been some work done to fix this for future releases on the 8.5 line, but I know there's not been any releases since we discovered this. It might be worth filing a bug: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=12997&atid=112997